# Case sensitivity in Session Attributes

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, case-sensitive

Is there case sensitivity in session attributes?

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("Contract");

request.getSession().getAttribute("contract");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is case sensitive, request attributes as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there case sensitivity in session attributes?

Yes.

Comment: You could have tested this yourself in the time it took to write the question.